# Can I disable insert-mode completion (ins-completion) key mapping (CTRL-X)?

Tags: key-bindings, autocompletion, ins-completion

Because the keys `d` and `x`are used in normal mode to delete letters, I map `<ctrl-d>` and `<ctrl-x>` in insert mode to `delete` and `backspace`.

However, when I started to use completion plugin (I use *supertab* now, though it doesn't update recently, it still works good), if I press `<ctrl-x>` in insert mode, vim jump into *CTRL-X mode*. 

After searching, I found that key `<ctrl-x>` actually predefined in ins-completion feature. Because using *supertab* I can use `<tab>` to search completion, I still want to use `<ctrl-x>` as `backspace` in insert mode. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as though the supertab plugin has either overwritten or removed your insert mode mapping. You can check if this is the case with the command:

```
:verbose imap <C-X>
```

You can reinstate your mapping simply by re-running your map command again:

```
:inoremap <C-X> <BS>
```

The best way to do this automatically in your vim configuration is probably to use the `after` directory [as suggested by @filbranden in the comments](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21083/can-i-disable-insert-mode-completion-ins-completion-key-mapping-ctrl-x#comment36967_21084):

Create a `.vim` file with any name in the location:

```
~/.vim/after/plugin/
```

with the contents:

```
inoremap <C-X> <BS>
```

This will be run after supertab (and all other plugins) and so can override its settings. See `:help after-directory` for more details.

Comment: I execute `:verbose imap <C-X>`, it says `Last set from .......supertab\plugin\supertab.vim`

Comment: I guess I can add autocmd to remap `<ctrl-x>` when I enter insert mode

Comment: I add command `autocmd InsertEnter * inoremap <C-x> <BS>` in my .vimrc, and works, thank you

Comment: The best way to override settings from plug-ins is in files under `~/.vim/after`, which are run after plug-ins load. In this case, putting `inoremap <C-x> <bs>` in `~/.vim/after/plugin/ctrl-x.vim` (or any other file `*.vim` in that directory) would solve that.

Comment: @filbranden Huh. For some reason I had it in my head when I wrote this answer that some plugin managers actually load plugins with `:runtime` rather than just manipulating the `'rtp'`, in which case it would be arguably simpler just to move the setting further down in your `vimrc`. I can't find any evidence that this is true now, though. I'll update my answer to include your suggestion.